Breakpoints in VSCode not working with Deno 2.0 + Next.js
I'm trying to debug a Next.js project in VS Code using Deno 2.0.
However, none of the breakpoints are working. They’re simply being ignored.
Where is my .vscode/launch.json:
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "type": "node",
      "program": "npm:next",
      "args": ["dev"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "env": {},
      "runtimeExecutable": "/opt/homebrew/bin/deno",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "run",
        "--unstable",
        "--inspect-brk",
        "--allow-all"
      ],
      "attachSimplePort": 9229,
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
  ]
}

Everything seems to be working:
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/ws/89519193-15c2-42e4-b0d7-8eec85e2b3cc
Visit chrome://inspect to connect to the debugger.
Deno is waiting for debugger to connect.
Debugger session started.
  ▲ Next.js 14.2.15
  - Local:        http://localhost:3000
  - Environments: .env

 ✓ Starting...
 ✓ Ready in 1859ms


Debug is broken in the latest version of VS Code (1.95.1).
(https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/232651).
You need to deactivate AutoUpdate and install the 1.94.2 version until they repaired it (1.95.2?)

I'm currently using VS Code version 1.93.1.
